# SQL query with additional 'nearest' row

Tags: sql, sqlite, select-query

Consider the following table structure:

```
id   speed 
 1   100
 2   200
 3   300
 4   400
 5   500
```

Consider the following query: `"SELECT * FROM records WHERE speed >= 300"` - this will return the rows #3, 4, 5. Is there a way to modify this query so that with the same `300` speed parameter it would also return the first row that does not fit the condition i.e. #2. So that the end results would be rows #2, 3, 4, 5?

UPD: Note that all the values and the records count here are arbitrary and for example only. The database is SQLite.

Comment: What version of SQL?  Sql Server?  MySQL? Etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE Speed >= 300

UNION

SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Test
    WHERE Speed < 300
    ORDER BY Speed DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS XXX

ORDER BY Speed
```

See [DEMO](http://rextester.com/STRV47088)

**Note**: changed for [SQLite syntax](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/eb321/1/0).

Comment: I agree with the idea to just union the one row that is nearest, but this is `SQL Server` syntax and the question is tagged `SQLite`

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Yeah, sorry for that. Should replace `TOP` with `LIMIT`, but I can not check, cause http://sqlfiddle.com/ is not available.

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple query, which selects the row with the maximum id and speed < 300 as well as rows with speed >= 300.

```
SELECT * 
FROM records 
WHERE speed >= 300
OR id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM records WHERE speed < 300)
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: This is a little bit wrong in case when ID is in other order than Speed, i.e.: ID 1 - Speed 200 and ID 2 - Speed 100.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from records
order by abs(300 - speed) asc
limit 5
```

Comment: What if you have no idea, how many rows are there? Meaning that '5' is not a constant, but a variable?

Comment: IIRC `TOP` wont work with `SQLITE` it should rather be `LIMIT 5` at the end, shouldn't it?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: Absolutely. I was under the implession it was SQLServer.